# How to create an outliner and parent it to a widget using PySide in Maya?

Tags: pyside, maya, outliner

I have a ui which was created using "Qt Designer". Then pysideuic.compileUi() was used to convert the ".ui" file to ".py" file. It successfully loads in Maya. How to parent a new outliner to one of its widget.

I think this is an example using PyQt but I can't do the same using PySide:
[Maya Outliner in Pyqt doesn't charge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778552/maya-outliner-in-pyqt-doesnt-charge)

Please let me know if you need more detail on the question.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Turns out layouts are not considered widgets in Qt, but they are in Maya!

So when we want to get a panel from a window created in QtDesigner, we need to pass the name of the layout attached to a widget, not the name of the widget itself.

```
ptr = getCppPointer(self.ui.vl_outliner)
panel = omui.MQtUtil.fullName(long(ptr[0]))
cmds.setParent(panel)
```

In code above, vl_outliner is the name of the vertical layout attached to QFrame, not the name of QFrame itself.